# Open dialog, split and multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

I'm new to coding and I have a pseudo specific question (it's for a class using visual studio 2017). I need to read a user selected file into an array. (OpenDialog I know) The array needs to be dynamically sized. I need the file to split properly during import (like through all punctuation). I have this

```
char[] delimiters = { ',', '-', ' ' };
string[] parsedData = dataInput.Split(delimiters);
```

The first two fields will never change (name and  email), but the number of columns of grades following this can vary. (Keep in mind it’s a CSV file)

I know I need a multidimensional array but I can't get it to work... ALSO

If our chosen file reads correctly, I need it to say that in an error log. If any value is wrong, state it in the error log and leave the field blank in the array?

[Basically here's what the raw data will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAZ42.jpg)

Comment: consider using a csv parser

Comment: this is a long: Do my Homework question. If you haven't learned enough in class to solve this go back to the teacher. During the test we are not there to make your test within the time limit

Comment: why post an image of a CSV file when you can copy paste a few lines of text in triple back ticks block

Comment: As @rioV8 says - while we would be able to offer a myriad of options for doing this, it'd probably bypass whatever the lesson is intending to _actually_ teach you at this point, and may be detrimental.  Going back over the course material and/or speaking to your tutor is the best course of action here.

Comment: "I know I need a multidimensional array" - a List of a Class with appropriate members is what you need ;)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need a multidim-ed array; that's rarely a good choice.  You will not get a good answer to this question as you have it.  1st, you need to edit it, remove the image, and paste in your _raw data_ as text.  After you have done this, select it  & press the `{}` button on the question editor, and the data will show up as `code`. Then you need to show us the code you have written (not just comment _OpenDialog I know_ and explain what's working and what is not.  We aren't going to do your homework for you, but if you show us you are trying, we will try to help

Comment: your only delimiter is `,` and be aware that if you encounter a `"` every thing until the next `"` is one field, so just splitting the input string is a bad thing you have to go over char by char and make decisions what to do with this character, add to the current field or start a new fields based on if you are in a quoted string

Comment: Here's a hint.  Start by declaring a class that looks like `public class GradeItem { string Name {get; set;} string Email {get; set;} List<decimal> Grades {get; set;} = new List<decimal>(); public void AddGrade (decimal gradeValue) {Grades.Add(gradeValue; }`.  Then declare a `List<GradeItem>` and go from there

Comment: I hope that's all fake user data you just posted.  `user@example.com` would be a fine placeholder for an actual email address.

Comment: @Wyck That is my secret email address, `fake@bar.com` might be a better choice

Comment: @rioV8 `example.com`, `example.net`, `example.org` and `*.example` are all reserved by [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606.txt) for things like documentation and examples.  Whereas bar.com is a real domain.  Of course, if you're joking, I'll admit to a _whoosh_, but I didn't see a winky-face.